# winapi c listview

Tags: c++, winapi, listview

I created a listView:

```
ListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT,
            50,50,200,100,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_LISTV,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
```

after that I fill with data

And after that I would like to delete all item and column. how can i do this?
thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? MSDN contains simepl examples to do everything you've said, so I assume you've tried them and they didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clear a listview's contents using the `LVM_DELETEALLITEMS` message (or associated macro):

```
ListView_DeleteAllItems(ListView);
```

You can delete columns using the `LVM_DELETECOLUMN` message. There's no way to delete them all at once; you need to do them one by one.

Comment: yes thanks thats work, but I forget to mention that I would like to clear all item and COLUMN.

Comment: Use the `LVM_DELETECOLUMN` message, or the `ListView_DeleteColumn()` macro. You have to delete each column individually.

Comment: and any other solution that delete all column?

Comment: You asked for a way to delete all columns and got a very simple one. Make it into you own function if you want it simpler.